# How to update records form a from whose data source is set to view in Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

My oracle apex application has an events page that has a v_event view as its data source. This view contains all the column that an event table contains plus it also has club_name column that holds the name of the organizing club. The report displays correctly as I want it for now.
[image]

When I try to update a record I get an error saying 'data manipulation operation not legal on this view'
[image]

This must be because the data source for the page is a view. How can I solve this problem ?

Also when I try to create new events I get an error:

[image]

First I thought that the '... non key-preserved table' occurred because the relationship between event and club_event(junction table between club and event) table was one to many and same event row was repeating multiple times if there were multiple clubs organizing it. So to solve this issue I  "LISTAGG" clause to combine multiple club names for a single event in a single row using comma separation as you can see in the second row of the first image above. But it didn't solve the issue. What am I doing wrong?

By the way the entire page is a "report with form" that oracle apex provides. So I am able solve this problem by create a new page and setting its data source to event table. But I just wanted to learn if there is a way that I can create a new event through the view table.

Also one final question. How can I map the values in 'From College' and 'From Community' column in the first image to be "yes" if the value in the table is 1 and "no" is the value is 0 ?

Thank you.

Comment: It is very hard to answer multiple questions in a single post. The goal is for the information to be useful to other users of the site. If you ask multiple questions in a single thread, the thread loses all its value to the community.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there are several tables involved here. Even if it weren't for Apex, the answer is to create an **instead of trigger** which fires when view is updated, and then trigger body decides which tables are updated and how.

In Apex, you could - additionally - try to write your own processes that handle inserts, updates and deletes. In other words, don't use *automatic row processing* as it won't work, but create your processes.

As of mapping 1/0 to "yes/no":

- in (interactive) report, use `CASE` (or `DECODE`)
- in form, either create radio button or select list item

Answer (score 0):

The view needs to have a 1:1 mapping to the table and the column that has the "LISTAGG" should have the attribute "Source > Query Only" set to "On".